# Where is the firebase config informations in firebase or google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I try to start my project and I decide to use firebase and I create firebase database
and then I want to connect my database
but I can not find config informations.

Can someone explain me where is it

in firebase console ?
in google cloud console ?

where is it ??
why is hidden ??

I can not find config informations

Comment: I recommend starting from https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides, and picking the platform you're targeting. You can also find the relevant information in the Firebase console for your project: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/overview